# Validação do <input type="text" required name="name" ng-model="aviso.nome" />

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sinceramente, já faz 3 dias que eu estou tentando validar um input, o negócio teoricamente parece simples, mas na prática não está validando nada.

A Situação ta a seguinte:

> Esse é uma parte do meu index.html

```
<script>
    function checkForm(form) {
        // validation fails if the input is blank
        if (form.name.value == null || form.name.value == '' || form.name.value == "") {
            alert("Existe Algum Campo Vazio (Isso Não Pode Acontecer)");
            form.name.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } </script>
```

> Aqui vem meu head seguido do form

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
        <div>
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="aviso.nome" required name="name"
                value="" aria-describedby="name-format" />  
        </div>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="SalvarAvisos()" /> 
        <input type="button" value="limparCampo"    ng-click="limparCampo()" />
</form>
```

Eu leigo todo, olhando assim me parece que tem que ter alguma validação no

> ng-click="SalvarAvisos()"

mas eu estou perdido, pq mesmo o campo estando vazio ou nulo, a mensagem de erro aparece, mas o formulário é enviado da mesma forma, sei que é enviado pq no banco aparece lá "null".

Obg por chegar até o final.
BomDia&BoasPesquisas

Comment: Se está usando angularjs porque não valida os elementos pelos seus models aplicado através do $context?

Comment: vou pesquisar sobre esse $context  , tem muita coisa de front, tô pegando esse ritmo de full ainda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anderson, deve haver um jeito melhor de validar isso, já que está utilizando Angular. Entretanto, aqui vai algumas edições que podem te satisfazer:

1. tire o evento `onsubmit` do `<form>` e adicione um `name` à ele (`name="formularioXYZ"`)
2. no método `checaForm()`, coloque `document.formularioXYZ.submit()` antes do `return true`
3. mude o `type="submit"` para `type="button"`

Se não quiser submeter, apenas executar `SalvarAvisos()`, faz assim:

1. tire o evento `onsubmit` do `<form>`;
2. no método `checaForm()`, coloque `SalvarAvisos()` antes do `return true`;
3. mude o `type="submit"` para `type="button"`;

Abraços e boa sorte com seu projeto!